# Using IdentityServer4 to protect my website and API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a website set up that is responsible for the rendering of information fetched from an API that I have built; both of which are in .NET Core 2.1.

I want the API to handle the authentication using Bearer tokens to ensure that users have the correct permissions to make the calls they're using. I also want to protect my server-server communications too, so that my website can make authenticated calls to the API, without users themselves being authenticated.

I have been following the tutorials for IdentityServer4 and I feel like it's something I should be using to achieve my desired workflow.

However, the tutorials all force the user to redirect to the IdentityServer application to log in. This doesn't feel seamless; I don't want my users being redirected to another domain for authentication; they shouldn't have to leave my site.

Is it possible to send the username and password to my API and have the API authenticate with IdentityServer without the user seeing what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: It is certainly possible and it is also highly undesirable. The API does not need to know at any point the credentials of the end user, that's why it's much more preferred to redirect to the IdSrv. Think of having to log in to Stack Overflow through Google: do you enter your gMail credentials into the Stack Overflow site or are you redirected to the gMail login site? Why would Stack Overflow want to know your Google credentials...? The exact same principle applies to this question

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But it's all my own systems that users will be logging into, I want the user experience to be that they're logging into "Ant's Website", not "Ant's Login Server". If I log into Stack Overflow using my Username/Password (not a third party), why should I be redirected away from the SO website... That's what it feels like IdSrv is doing... I'm new to all this so I'm ready to learn, but I just can't wrap my head around that bit...

Comment: Perhaps I don’t need IdSrv for this. Perhaps what I really need to figure out is how to authenticate a WebAPI using oAuth 2.0. I’m not sure; this is my first attempt at this and it just feels really confusing.

Comment: What you're describing is standard username/password authentication that is handled internally with Cookie authentication.  You don't need IdentityServer4 for that.  If your API is running on the same domain you don't even need Bearer tokens because Cookie authentication will do the job.  If your API is running on a separate domain then you can use Bearer tokens but you'll have to issue them yourself.